# how to install npm on ubuntu?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, mocha.js

I want to install mocha test framework but for this we need npm So I ran   following commands
1. `sudo apt-get install npm`
2. `npm install -g mocha`

But getting following error when I ran first command

```
user@dell:~/mochatest$ sudo apt-get install npm
[sudo] password for user: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  apt-clone archdetect-deb autogen ax25-node binutils-mingw-w64-i686
  binutils-mingw-w64-x86-64 dmraid g++-mingw-w64 g++-mingw-w64-i686
  g++-mingw-w64-x86-64 gcc-mingw-w64 gcc-mingw-w64-base gcc-mingw-w64-i686
  gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64 gfortran-mingw-w64 gfortran-mingw-w64-i686
  gfortran-mingw-w64-x86-64 gir1.2-json-1.0 gir1.2-timezonemap-1.0
  gir1.2-xkl-1.0 gnat-mingw-w64 gnat-mingw-w64-base gnat-mingw-w64-i686
  gnat-mingw-w64-x86-64 kpartx kpartx-boot libax25 libdebian-installer4
  libdevmapper-event1.02.1 libdmraid1.0.0.rc16 libopts25 libopts25-dev lvm2
  mingw-w64 mingw-w64-common mingw-w64-i686-dev mingw-w64-x86-64-dev
  openbsd-inetd python3-icu python3-pam quilt rdate watershed
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  node-abbrev node-ansi node-archy node-async node-block-stream
  node-combined-stream node-cookie-jar node-delayed-stream node-forever-agent
  node-form-data node-fstream node-fstream-ignore node-github-url-from-git
  node-glob node-graceful-fs node-gyp node-inherits node-ini
  node-json-stringify-safe node-lockfile node-lru-cache node-mime
  node-minimatch node-mkdirp node-mute-stream node-node-uuid node-nopt
  node-normalize-package-data node-npmlog node-once node-osenv node-qs
  node-read node-read-package-json node-request node-retry node-rimraf
  node-semver node-sha node-sigmund node-slide node-tar node-tunnel-agent
  node-which nodejs-dev
Suggested packages:
  node-hawk node-aws-sign node-oauth-sign node-http-signature
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  node-abbrev node-ansi node-archy node-async node-block-stream
  node-combined-stream node-cookie-jar node-delayed-stream node-forever-agent
  node-form-data node-fstream node-fstream-ignore node-github-url-from-git
  node-glob node-graceful-fs node-gyp node-inherits node-ini
  node-json-stringify-safe node-lockfile node-lru-cache node-mime
  node-minimatch node-mkdirp node-mute-stream node-node-uuid node-nopt
  node-normalize-package-data node-npmlog node-once node-osenv node-qs
  node-read node-read-package-json node-request node-retry node-rimraf
  node-semver node-sha node-sigmund node-slide node-tar node-tunnel-agent
  node-which nodejs-dev npm
0 upgraded, 46 newly installed, 0 to remove and 656 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/945 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4,780 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
E: Invalid archive signature
E: Internal error, could not locate member control.tar.{gzbz2xzlzma}
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/node-fstream_0.1.24-1_all.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/node-lru-cache_2.3.1-1_all.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/node-sigmund_1.0.0-1_all.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/node-minimatch_0.2.12-1_all.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/node-fstream-ignore_0.0.6-2_all.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/node-github-url-from-git_1.1.1-1_all.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/node-glob_3.2.6-1_all.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs-dev_0.10.25~dfsg2-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/node-nopt_2.1.2-1_all.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/node-npmlog_0.0.4-1_all.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/node-osenv_0.0.3-1_all.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/node-tunnel-agent_0.3.1-1_all.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/node-json-stringify-safe_5.0.0-1_all.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/node-qs_0.6.5-1_all.deb
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Selecting previously unselected package node-async.
(Reading database ... 194080 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../node-async_0.2.5-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-async (0.2.5-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-node-uuid.
Preparing to unpack .../node-node-uuid_1.4.0-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-node-uuid (1.4.0-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-abbrev.
Preparing to unpack .../node-abbrev_1.0.4-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-abbrev (1.0.4-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-ansi.
Preparing to unpack .../node-ansi_0.2.1-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-ansi (0.2.1-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-archy.
Preparing to unpack .../node-archy_0.0.2-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-archy (0.0.2-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-inherits.
Preparing to unpack .../node-inherits_2.0.0-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-inherits (2.0.0-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-block-stream.
Preparing to unpack .../node-block-stream_0.0.7-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-block-stream (0.0.7-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-delayed-stream.
Preparing to unpack .../node-delayed-stream_0.0.5-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-delayed-stream (0.0.5-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-combined-stream.
Preparing to unpack .../node-combined-stream_0.0.4-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-combined-stream (0.0.4-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-cookie-jar.
Preparing to unpack .../node-cookie-jar_0.3.1-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-cookie-jar (0.3.1-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-forever-agent.
Preparing to unpack .../node-forever-agent_0.5.1-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-forever-agent (0.5.1-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-mime.
Preparing to unpack .../node-mime_1.2.11-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-mime (1.2.11-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-form-data.
Preparing to unpack .../node-form-data_0.1.0-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-form-data (0.1.0-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-rimraf.
Preparing to unpack .../node-rimraf_2.2.2-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-rimraf (2.2.2-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-mkdirp.
Preparing to unpack .../node-mkdirp_0.3.5-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-mkdirp (0.3.5-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-graceful-fs.
Preparing to unpack .../node-graceful-fs_2.0.0-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-graceful-fs (2.0.0-2) ...
dpkg-deb: error: `/var/cache/apt/archives/node-fstream_0.1.24-1_all.deb' is not a debian format archive
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/node-fstream_0.1.24-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
Selecting previously unselected package node-lru-cache.
Preparing to unpack .../node-lru-cache_2.3.1-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-lru-cache (2.3.1-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-sigmund.
Preparing to unpack .../node-sigmund_1.0.0-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-sigmund (1.0.0-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-minimatch.
Preparing to unpack .../node-minimatch_0.2.12-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-minimatch (0.2.12-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-fstream-ignore.
Preparing to unpack .../node-fstream-ignore_0.0.6-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-fstream-ignore (0.0.6-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-github-url-from-git.
Preparing to unpack .../node-github-url-from-git_1.1.1-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-github-url-from-git (1.1.1-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-glob.
Preparing to unpack .../node-glob_3.2.6-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-glob (3.2.6-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nodejs-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../nodejs-dev_0.10.25~dfsg2-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nodejs-dev (0.10.25~dfsg2-2ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-nopt.
Preparing to unpack .../node-nopt_2.1.2-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-nopt (2.1.2-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-npmlog.
Preparing to unpack .../node-npmlog_0.0.4-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-npmlog (0.0.4-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-osenv.
Preparing to unpack .../node-osenv_0.0.3-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-osenv (0.0.3-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-tunnel-agent.
Preparing to unpack .../node-tunnel-agent_0.3.1-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-tunnel-agent (0.3.1-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-json-stringify-safe.
Preparing to unpack .../node-json-stringify-safe_5.0.0-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-json-stringify-safe (5.0.0-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-qs.
Preparing to unpack .../node-qs_0.6.5-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-qs (0.6.5-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-request.
Preparing to unpack .../node-request_2.26.1-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-request (2.26.1-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-semver.
Preparing to unpack .../node-semver_2.1.0-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-semver (2.1.0-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-tar.
Preparing to unpack .../node-tar_0.1.18-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-tar (0.1.18-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-which.
Preparing to unpack .../node-which_1.0.5-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-which (1.0.5-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-gyp.
Preparing to unpack .../node-gyp_0.10.10-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-gyp (0.10.10-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-ini.
Preparing to unpack .../node-ini_1.1.0-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-ini (1.1.0-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-lockfile.
Preparing to unpack .../node-lockfile_0.4.1-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-lockfile (0.4.1-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-mute-stream.
Preparing to unpack .../node-mute-stream_0.0.3-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-mute-stream (0.0.3-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-normalize-package-data.
Preparing to unpack .../node-normalize-package-data_0.2.2-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-normalize-package-data (0.2.2-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-once.
Preparing to unpack .../node-once_1.1.1-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-once (1.1.1-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-read.
Preparing to unpack .../node-read_1.0.4-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-read (1.0.4-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-read-package-json.
Preparing to unpack .../node-read-package-json_1.1.3-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-read-package-json (1.1.3-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-retry.
Preparing to unpack .../node-retry_0.6.0-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-retry (0.6.0-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-sha.
Preparing to unpack .../node-sha_1.2.3-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-sha (1.2.3-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-slide.
Preparing to unpack .../node-slide_1.1.4-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-slide (1.1.4-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package npm.
Preparing to unpack .../npm_1.3.10~dfsg-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking npm (1.3.10~dfsg-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for doc-base (0.10.5) ...
Processing 4 added doc-base files...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/node-fstream_0.1.24-1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When I ran `npm install -g mocha` I am getting following error.

user@dell:~/mochatest$

```
user@dell:~/mochatest$ npm install -g mocha
npm ERR! Error: Cannot find module 'fstream'
npm ERR!     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
npm ERR!     at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
npm ERR!     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
npm ERR!     at require (module.js:380:17)
npm ERR!     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/tar/lib/entry.js:14:15)
npm ERR!     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
npm ERR!     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
npm ERR!     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
npm ERR!     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
npm ERR!     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-36-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "mocha"
npm ERR! cwd /home/user//mochatest
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/mochatest/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use sudo to install npm packages globally in ubuntu.
Try

```
sudo npm install -g mocha
```

Comment: still I am getting same error, nodejs verison is `v0.10.25` and nop version is `1.3.10`
`

Comment: It should work. There is an issue report at npm with a similar error. Issue reporter says the error went away after reinstalling node(https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3282). Might want to give it a try.

Comment: Also try "npm cache clean" before installing mocha